# Exterior below grade insulation damaged by contractor

Tags: insulation

[image]Our newly built home has mineral wool exterior below grade insulation on the foundation.  To install electric for landscaping / motorized pergola, the installer hand dug a trench. I was shocked to see that he dug right up against the foundation, and the digging tore off chunks of insulation approximately 4 inches high all along the 20 ft wall.   Does this matter, and is there any way to repair it?  It seems like it is not good to me; that it was there for a reason.  Any advice would be very much appreciated.  There was no need to dig that close to the foundation, in case anyone wonders.  I attached a picture that shows the area.

Comment: Is the wire that's shown the wire that is supposed to be buried?

Comment: Yes, that's it.  I think it can be pushed back a bit to give more room to work in there.